# Creating instance of an object which implements a given interface

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to construct an object with Activator.CreateInstance(), however i am receiving null for some unknown to me reason.

```
public class SpawnManager
{

    public void CreateSpawnable<T>()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        ISpawnable<SpawnableParameters> spawnable = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ISpawnable<SpawnableParameters>;

        // the spawnable object always returns null
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        CreateSpawnable<SpawnableCollectible>();
    }

}


public class SpawnableCollectible : ISpawnable<ParametersCollectible>
{

    public void Spawn(ParametersCollectible parameters)
    {
    }

}
```

Can somebody explain why i can't create an object instance which implements the given interface like that and write the correct approach for instantiating such an object?

Comment: You can find such mistakes yourself by using the debugger to look at the runtime values of all computations involved. See the answer.

Comment: Where is definition of `SpawnableParameters`?

Comment: public abstract class SpawnableParameters
{
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your types do not match. `SpawnableCollectible` implements `ISpawnable<ParametersCollectible>` not `ISpawnable<SpawnableParameters>` so the cast fails and `as` operator returns *null*.

Comment: Thanks. So how should I correctly approach this certain scenario?

Comment: implement the correct interface in your type. Or, cast it to correct type.

Comment: Casting to the correct type: `var spawnable = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);`

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Selman22 said:

You'll probably want to constrain `T` to be a type that derives from `ISpawnable<SpawnableParameters>`.
This will fix your problem:

```
public void CreateSpawnable<T>() where T: ISpawnable<SpawnableParameters>
{
    //...
}
```

This way, the client code cannot invoke your method with an invalid type `T`, and the `as` cast will always succeed.